# How to call functions within order-only prerequisites?

Tags: makefile

Given this bit of Makefile:

```
# for pattern matching
$(OBJDIR) := build

# just to see if a level of indirection will work
my_dir = $(dir $(1))

$(OBJECTS) : $(OBJDIR)/% : $(HEADERS) $(SRCDIR)/% | % $(dir %) $(call my_dir,%)
  @echo output-only = $|
```

This is a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) with [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types).

Consider the target "build/utility/debug.js". The output of the above rule will be this:

```
output-only = utility/debug.js ./
```

- The first component, "utility/debug.js", is properly copied from the stem (%).
- The second component, "./", is the output of calling the `dir` function in the prerequisites list.
- The third component, an empty string, is the output of calling my `my_dir` function in the prerequisites list.

If I change `my_dir` to this:

```
my_dir = $(1)
```

The output remains the same. If I change it to this:

```
my_dir = "foo"
```

Then make complains there is no rule to make "foo" (which is expected). It appears, then, that `$(1)` is not getting bound in the call to `my_dir`.

What's going on? Why can't I pass the stem to a function? I have a workaround that uses secondary expansion, but I want to know why I can't write my rule this way.

**EDIT:** I'm new to stackoverflow, forgive me if this is not the way things are done here.

I want $(1) because I am passing the stem as an argument to `my_dir`, as Alex pointed out.

I don't know why it was suggested I want "$". I don't believe $ by itself expands to anything in any context.

I know that automatic variables are only available in the recipe. I am not using an automatic variable in the prerequisites - I am using the stem:

> Each target is matched against the target-pattern to extract a part of the target name, called the stem. This stem is substituted into each of the prereq-patterns to make the prerequisite names (one from each prereq-pattern). [- the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage)

The fact that the stem is available is demonstrated by the example: the stem expands to the correct value when used alone, but not when passed to a function.

Comment: actually `%` stem character is processed after finished the expanstion of variables and functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in [this section of the GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reading-Makefiles), variable and function references in the list of prerequisites are immediately expanded, during the read in phase. This means, before any pattern matching is done, so the `%` has no special meaning yet; it is interpreted as a literal character in the two function references, `$(dir %)` and `$(call my_dir,%)`, both having `./` as a result, which get merged in the reference to `$|` in the recipe.

I don't know of any other workaround than the one you already found, i.e. secondary expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Note `$1` is not a special variable that expands to anything interesting related to pattern rules (or static pattern rules).  The `$1` variable only has unique behavior within the context of a user-defined macro invoked by the `$(call ...)` function.

You wanted to use `$*`, not `$1`; `$*` is an automatic variable which expands to the stem of the target of the rule.

However, in all versions of make (including the POSIX standard definition of make), automatic variables (including `$*`, `$<`, `$@`, `$^`, etc.) are only available in the context of the recipe.  They are not available in the context of the target or prerequisite lists.  See the [GNU make manual section on Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) for more details.

As you suggest, there is a GNU make-specific feature enabled by the .SECONDEXPANSION pseudo target which provides a way to avoid this limitation.

Comment: Not quite - he actually wants the `$1` within the macro `my_dir` to be the argument. The mistake he's making is the other point you bring up, that the automatic variables are only available within the context of the recipe (and not in the target or prerequisite lists).

Comment: Sorry, I was concentrating on the `$(dir %)` prerequisite, not the `$(call my_dir,%)` prerequisite.  And my formatting was wrong so `$*` expanded to `$`.  A bad answer all the way around.  Anyway the reasoning given by eriktous is correct: all variables/functions in target/prereq lists are expanded immediately when the makefile is read in **long** before the implicit rule is matched.  This is required by POSIX.  The secondary expansion feature was created specifically to allow deferring of expansion until later, when the implicit rule is matched.