# GNU make's prerequisite expansion is not lazy

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In the GNU `make`, apparently the prerequisites for the rules are [expanded immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9533980/360695). Consider:

```
AAA = task1
all: ${AAA} ; @echo finalizing
task1: ; @echo task1
task2: ; @echo task2
AAA += task2
```

This would print only `task1`, but not `task2`, since at the moment of parsing the `all` rule, the variable `${AAA}` held only the `task1`.

Is there any workaround for that? Or some way to make the `make` expand the variables lazily, like it does inside the commands?

P.S. In my case the `${AAA}` variables is set/changed inside included files. Most are included at the top. Few are included at the bottom - and they are affected. I can't simply move all the include files to the top, since that messes up the default rule. And I can't easily add the extra prereqs to the rules, since there are multiple rules which rely on multiple variables (would lead to lots of copy-paste). The only ideas I have come up with so far were (A) to extract the final value of the variable and call `make` recursively with its full value ([based on the suggestion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427542/360695)) or (B) move the variabe from prerequisites to the command and loop over it calling `make` recursively for every prerequisite. I'd love to have a more elegant alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is clearly spelled out in the GNU make manual, [here for example](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html).

An alternative you can consider is [secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Secondary-Expansion.html) which will let you defer the expansion of the variable until run-time.

However you don't need to do that.  You are forgetting that you can add more prerequisites to a rule whenever you want.  All you have to do is write your makefiles like this:

```
AAA = task1
all: ; @echo finalizing
task1: ; @echo task1
task2: ; @echo task2
AAA += task2

all: ${AAA}
```

As long as you can arrange for a final section to always be placed at the end you can add the prerequisites there and be sure that the variable assignments have all completed.  This is also a lot more portable, if you care about that.

Also, you can force the default target to be whatever you want just by mentioning it first, you don't need to give it a recipe.  So you could also write this if you wanted:

```
all:
AAA = task1
task1: ; @echo task1
task2: ; @echo task2
AAA += task2

all: ${AAA} ; @echo finalizing
```

Comment: I have includes (where variables come from) and as I have said, I can't just move stuff around. Neither the include files have freedom to make assumptions about the targets in the `Makefile` they are included in. The secondary expansion also inapplicable since I have (again) includes at the end of the file and it might potentially break if there is a `$` character in the prereq file name. (Not at the moment, but this is a silly limitation to impose.)

Comment: I didn't suggest that you "move stuff around"; more that you add new stuff at the beginning or end.  If you add `all:` by itself at the beginning then you've ensured that this is the default target, and you haven't forced anything else to change.  If you add `all: ${AAA}` at the end then you've ensured `all` depends on all values added to `AAA` anywhere in the makefile or its included files.  I don't see why this is more problematic than the changes you're already considering (using recursive make etc.) but if you can't do it then I guess you're out of luck.